# How do I get the date of birth from a full age in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an age on the format `57 years 5 months 7 days`, and I want to deduct the date of birth from it in postgresql on a format like `yyyy-mm-dd`, how do I do that?

Comment: You can't do this easily in SQL, as you have to consider leap years in the process. Why do you have such a lousy format being stored at all (as it will become invalid tomorrow) instead of just storing the birthdate itself?

Comment: I am just in the process of organizing data from an old database and I want to create a new column with the date of birth instead of that messy format

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN If it's an old database then those birthdates will be relative to some point in the past - I assume you're accounting for that?

Comment: Yes, I am accounting for that point in the past. Thanks for pointing it out @Dai

Comment: @KenWhite: it's as simple as `current_date - '57 years 5 months 7 days'::interval`

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. That being said, it's worth noting that in a real scenario like mine, you need to replace `current_date` by an actual fixed point in time since a birthday is a fixed date. @KenWhite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the past date using multiple `intervals`. I added a couple examples to the data to check that it's working.

```
select  *
       ,current_date + (interval '-1 years'*years) + (interval '-1 month'*months) + (interval '-1 day'*days) as dte
from    t
```

| years | months | days | dte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 57 | 5 | 7 | 1965-04-18 00:00:00 |
| 36 | 11 | 12 | 1985-10-13 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 2016-07-24 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k5d4IS_0)

Comment: I will just need to remove the part with the time as it is unecessary in my scenario

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN: Just cast the result to a DATE if you don't want a TIMESTAMP

Comment: There is no need to split up the string. The example value can be cast to an interval directly: `current_date - '57 years 5 months 7 days'::interval`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there's actually a better way. I'll post it asap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `concat_ws`

```
   select *, current_date - concat_ws (' ', years, 'years', months, 'months', days, 'days')::interval as dte
    from   t
```

Here's a way with `make_interval`

```
select *, current_date - make_interval(years, months, 0, days) as dte
from   t
```

Here's a way with `format`

```
select *, current_date - format('%s years %s months %s days', years, months, days)::interval as dte
from   t
```

| years | months | days | dte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 57 | 5 | 7 | 1965-04-18 00:00:00 |
| 36 | 11 | 12 | 1985-10-13 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 2016-07-24 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Hw-gHOs)